# Proof remainder of polynomial division GF(2) can be calculated by LSFR

Tags: reference-request, polynomials, galois-theory, finite-fields

I have been [reading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computation_of_cyclic_redundancy_checks) that CRC, which is the calculation of the remainder of $x/P(x)$ in GF(2) can be implemented with a Linear Shift Feedback Register. However, I can't find the proof for this, or think of a way to prove this.